# Router not booting up

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, boot, router

I have UTSTARCOM WA3002G4 router.Recently, this router is very slow in booting up.When it is switched on, it lights up and stays it like that for over 2 hours and then the lights starts blinking and after few seconds it starts working perfectly.

I have not played with any settings of the router like upgrading firmware or like that.It is very frustrating.

I could use this router without ever turning it off to avoid the delay in booting up, but unfortunately power cuts are daily phenomenon

I am wondering if there is any solution for this problem...do you have?

Comment: Was it working before?

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the DSL router to a different phone jack in your location to verify it's not an issue with the line.

Try looking for and applying any firmware upgrades.

If you are constantly getting power interruptions, damaging spikes and surges may be affecting the equipment.  Try replacing the DSL router's power adapter or the router itself.  You should invest in an office-quality small UPS which can help prevent that.

Comment: I actually bought a new router - netgear n150, but that router is also driving me crazy with disconnections so now I'm here wondering if there is any way to fix my old router..vBut anyway thanks for the tip, I guess I should plug router to UPS.

Comment: That's almost definitely a phone line issue. Make sure *every* device connected to your phone line has a proper DSL filter. It's easy to miss things like alarm systems, satellite TV receivers, and the like. It's easy to move a phone or add a device and forget to put a filter before it.